# Elementary won't boot off USB Drive

Tags: software-installation

I'm trying to switch my computer from Windows to Elementary OS.  It's just so much of a hassle to keep up with updates that I don't even have the storage space for.  I'm trying to do this on a Lenovo IdeaPad 110S which has the following specs:
Intel Celeron - 2GB Memory - 32GB eMMC Flash Memory

I created a bootable USB which works fine on my office computer but doesn't boot on the Lenovo.  I hold down  &  which brings me to a boot menu but after selecting the USB all I get is a black screen that just hangs there.  I used RUFUS and downloaded the latest Elementary.  Anyone have any idea as to why it's not working on my Lenovo? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue: There was a BIOS option marked "Secure Boot" or something like that. I'm unsure what it does but I decided to disable it and BINGO.

Answer (score 0):

As the developers state on [the installation page of their website](https://elementary.io/docs/installation#installation) these are the recommended system requirments for *elementary OS*:

- Recent Intel i3 or comparable dualcore 64bit processor
- 4 GB of system memory (RAM)
- Solid state drive (SSD) with 15 GB of free space
- Internet access
- 1024×768 display

Even though they clearly say, these are not the required specifications for running elementary os, maybe it's not the distro you want to choose for your system in the first place.

However have you already tried different usb ports on your device and reinstalling the .iso to the usb drive (maybe using a different program to do that)?

**Update:**
Have you already read [this post](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16542/unable-to-install-elementary-juno-on-lenovo-ideapad-120s)? The guy fixed a very similar problem by updating his BIOS-Firmware, maybe that does the job for you aswell.